# JQuery send JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

I need to send json data via POST, so
in my var **request** has the structure of the json object

Anytime a button is clicked, I call this function:

```
function sendJSON(p_id, p_type) {
        var request=[{
          "id":null,
          "version":null,
          "type":null,
          "enabled":false,
          "priority":null,
          "params":[
            {
              "id":null,
              "version":null,
              "value":p_id,
            },
            {
              "id":null,
              "version":null,
              "value":p_type,
              "valueXML":null,
              "editable":false,
            }
          ],
          "lastEX":null
        }
        ];
        console.log(request);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.4.6:8080/recList/',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: request ,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                var resp = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(resp);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("err");
            }
        });
    };
```

I can't figure it out why it doesn't work
Did I forget something?

```
Request URL:http://192.168.4.6:8080/recList/
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
```

Comment: Why do you use JSON.stringify? You can send the request as an object if you want.

Comment: gonna try it without stringfy

Comment: status code is 200, so it should be ok. maybe the JSON.parse fails - did you tried to debug the success-callback?

Comment: request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.4.6:8080/recList/' is therefore not allowed access.

xHR failed loading: POST

Comment: What's the domain you're sending the request from? The exact url?

Comment: So you're trying to access a local machine (with an internal IP address (based on the 192.168)) from a machine that is outside of your network? That will never work.

Comment: I'll try to explain better:

I have RESTFUL service running on wildfly, at 
http://192.168.4.6:8080/recList/

The frontend instead is running on a tomcat at:
http://192.168.4.16:9080/

Comment: Have you added CORS support on the server-side? Requests from one port number to another (even if on the same domain / IP) are considered to be cross-origin.

Answer (score 1):

Your Json variable is

```
request=[{..}];
```

Please try to remove outer square brackets i.e '[' and ']'.

Then your request variable is:

```
var request={
      "id":null,
      "version":null,
      "type":null,
      "enabled":false,
      "priority":null,
      "params":[
        {
          "id":null,
          "version":null,
          "value":p_id,
        },
        {
          "id":null,
          "version":null,
          "value":p_type,
          "valueXML":null,
          "editable":false,
        }
      ],
      "lastEX":null
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

change `type: 'POST'` to `method: 'POST',`

Comment: query string parameters:
undefined=undefined

Comment: with data: JSON.stringify(request)

it's not undefined

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

pass your request variable in the data as shown below

```
data : {'data':request}
```

and access the data in your function using 'data' key.